# There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jsp

I am trying to implement Hibernate with Spring Boot web app, but I always get the same error in page: "**There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500)**."

Here is my Controller class:

```java
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    static SessionFactory factory;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    String mainPage() {
        return "mainPage";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent")
    String addStudent() {
        return "addStudent";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudents")
    String getStudents(Model model) {
        ArrayList<Student> allStudents = getAllStudents();
        model.addAttribute("allStudents", allStudents);
        for(Student s : allStudents) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }   
        System.out.println("done");
        return "StudentList";
    }

    @Autowired
    static ArrayList<Student> getAllStudents(){
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        ArrayList<Student> allStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();
        try {
            allStudents = (ArrayList<Student>) session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM students").list();
        }catch(HibernateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            return allStudents;
        }
    }
}
```

and my Student class:

```java
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [name=" + name + ", surname=" + surname + ", id=" + id + "]";
    }
}
```

**And I am always getting this error:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.example.demo.MainController.getAllStudents(MainController.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.MainController.getStudents(MainController.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
```

Comment: Spring will never, ever autowire a static field.

Comment: I suppose you think about sessionFactory, how should I write it?

Comment: Without a static modifier.

Comment: OK, and if I want to use it in the same class?

Comment: Well, use it. Instance fields can be used in a class. If they couldn't, what would they be useful for? Look at your Student class for example: all its methods use one or more of its instance fields.

Comment: I changed sessionFactory to instance field and getAllStudents to the non-static method, run it, but I am still getting same error and this one too: "Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: Why do you have `@Autowired` annotation on `getAllStudents()` method?

Comment: You then have to read the stack trace of the exception, as for every exception, to understand where the NullPointerException comes from.

Comment: I actually don't have, I deleted it during my last fix.

Comment: So where should I have @Autowired? Just above "SessionFactory factory;", and nowhere else right?

Comment: Yes, thats correct, I hope you initialized the @Bean
 public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
  LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
  return sessionFactory;
 }

Comment: Hmm, I am pretty new to all of this so I haven't done that and I don't even know where should Ii put that. Could u give me some more pointer?

Comment: checkout the answer, only since you are doing this first time

Answer (score 0):

From Spring Boot Documentation

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-sql

> The Spring Framework provides extensive support for working with SQL
> databases
>
> You application.properties file should have configured the database
> you are using for example for MySQL
>
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
>
> spring.datasource.username=dbuser
>
> spring.datasource.password=dbpass
>
> spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

And then inject

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;


public ArrayList<Student> getAllStudents(){
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Transaction tx = null;
        ArrayList<Student> allStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();
        try {
            allStudents = (ArrayList<Student>) session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM students").list();
        }catch(HibernateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            return allStudents;
        }
    }
```